# Is there a list of readymade Theme Frameworks for Asp.net web development

Tags: asp.net, themes, 960.gs, skins

As for Php there are loads of Theme frameworks warp5 etc. But is there a single Theme framework OR some framework  with which I can rapidly develop wireframes and prototypes for new website being created. I primarily use 960Gs for the css stuff. but this isn't a consideration for the theme framework you suggest. I am open to suggestions on the Css parts too.

Comment: Retagged from 'design' to 'web-design'

Comment: If all you are doign is wireframe/prototype what more do you need besides css and general controls (html or server side)?  What part of the framework needs to be asp.net related?  I use blue print css for my wireframe, but thats just ordinary css.

Comment: @Patricker something like backend controls where i can change the column layout, change styles dynamically. Have you seen Gantry for example that would give you a Idea here is the link [Gantry Framework](http://www.gantry-framework.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using JQueryUI that is pretty easily themeable http://jqueryui.com/themeroller

Comment: had you seen my earlier suggestions to get idea on what i wanted